Issue with survey package version 4.2.2
Facing issues with survey package version 4.2.2 in R, getting standard error as Inf with warning message.
I am using a dataset that has multi-stage stratification, and have to adjust for one or more strata there is one PSU, which I adjust for using options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust"). Below the survey design and estimate I am trying to get
#creating country design
c_design=svydesign(id=~PSU_ID,strata=~STATE_STRATUM,weights=~c_weight,data=df,nest = TRUE) 
#creating state design
s_design=svydesign(id=~PSU_ID,strata=~STATE_STRATUM,weights=~s_weight,data=df,nest = TRUE) 
#Generating estimate at country level 
est_country=svyby(formula = ~constant,by=~country+VAR_1,design = c_design,FUN = svytotal)

The warning message that I get is shown below
Warning messages:
1: In tapply(X = nPSU, INDEX = as.numeric(strata), FUN = head, 1) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In tapply(X = nPSU, INDEX = as.numeric(strata), FUN = head, 1) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In tapply(X = nPSU, INDEX = as.numeric(strata), FUN = head, 1) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
4: In tapply(X = nPSU, INDEX = as.numeric(strata), FUN = head, 1) :
  NAs introduced by coercion```

In the output, the standard errors are coming as Inf, while using the previous version 4.2.1 standard errors came as numbers with no warning message.

hi, i am not seeing a version 4.2.2 of the survey package?  http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/survey/NEWS  are you referring to version 4.2 vs 4.2-1  ?  would it be possible for you to reproduce this behavior with the current version (4.4-2) and with a public use dataset?  thanks!

You need to use a factor variable rather than a character string for your stratum variable, eg
c_design=svydesign(id=~PSU_ID,strata=~factor(STATE_STRATUM),weights=~c_weight,data=df,nest = TRUE) 

